# Input/output while debugging with GDB in WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've started working with Visual Studio Code on Windows & I want to debug the following file

**main.c** (located at *C:/Users/aibrakov/Projects/c* directory):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 42;  // add breakpoint here
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Following this threads

- [C\C++ in VS Code with Linux Subsystem For Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244620/c-c-in-vs-code-with-linux-subsystem-for-windows)
- [Visual Studio Code and Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) GCC/GDB integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126264/visual-studio-code-and-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-gcc-gdb-integration)

I have

**settings.json**:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "c:\\windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
}
```

**tasks.json**:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g", "main.c"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/mnt/c/Users/aibrakov/Projects/c/a.out",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/mnt/c/Users/aibrakov/Projects/c",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeCwd": "",
                "pipeProgram": "c:\\windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe",
                "pipeArgs": [
                    "-c"
                ],
                "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/mnt/c": "c:\\"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Building project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> succeeds.

Debugging kinda works: it stops on breakpoints and `DEBUG CONSOLE` tab is accessible, but I don't get output (`Hello World!` in my example) and also can't send character which `getchar` awaits.

Is there a way to work with the terminal in which my program is running? Or am I missing something?